# User input VM name should start via powerhsell

Tags: powershell

Purpose - I am trying to start vm if it is in stop state 
           Note - user will input Vm name , if its stop then it will start otherwise it will pop up that server already in started state.

```
$user = 'tooltest'  #Vmname
$rg = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup
$data= $rg.ResourceGroupName
foreach ( $d in $data){
    $res = Get-AzureRmResource | Where-Object {$_.ResourceGroupName -eq $d}
    if ( $res.Name -eq $user){
        Write-Output $res.Name
        Write-Output $res.ResourceGroupName

        $gg = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName [string]$res.ResourceGroupName -Name $user -Status
```

If i m trying to print $res.ResourceGroupName   - i am getting output of resourcegroup name 26 times (26 resources i have in That RG)
I wanted to print RG only one time , can anybody help me on that

Comment: [1] where is the rest of your `foreach` loop? i don't see the close of that loop ... [2] it looks like you are looping thru the entire set ... and printing out each loop. that seems like it would print all your resources & their groups.

Comment: Have you tried to pipe the `GET` to `Select-Object` like this: `$gg = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName [string]$res.ResourceGroupName -Name $user -Status | Select -Frist 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to filter your output is just to select how many objects do you want with the `Select-Object` cmdlet.

```
Write-Output $res.ResourceGroupName | Select -First 1
```

Comment: Hi erik,
   Thanks for your response , but still i am getting same error " $count2 = $res.ResourceGroupName
 $gg = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName [string]$count2 -Name $user -Status | select -First 1
  $gg
Get-AzureRmVM : Resource group '[string]VijayG-RG VijayG-RG VijayG-RG VijayG-RG VijayG-RG VijayG-RG VijayG-RG VijayG-RG VijayG-RG VijayG-RG VijayG-RG 
VIJAYG-RG VIJAYG-RG VijayG-RG VIJAYG-RG VIJAYG-RG VijayG-RG VIJAYG-RG VIJAYG-RG VijayG-RG VijayG-RG VijayG-RG VijayG-RG VijayG-RG VijayG-RG VijayG-RG' could 
not be found

Comment: Sorry, wrong line to apply the `Select` try with `Write-Output $res.ResourceGroupName | Select -First 1`